# org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.processHeader Invalid message received with signature 18245

Tags: apache, tomcat, nio, ajp

Occasionally we see the following in the Tomcat logs:

```
SEVERE [ajp-nio-8009-exec-3] org.apache.coyote.ajp.AjpMessage.processHeader Invalid message received with signature 18245
```

Any thoughts on what could be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it means that one of internal process has tried calling that port with http protocol. In my case, you got this issue when I use "wget"; it's not support a ajp protocol.

Either you listen to your port on http protocol, or you open another http port where your internal process should call.